# AngularJS testing $httpBackend.whenGET().respond() not working with number as parameter

Tags: angularjs, httpbackend

This test:

```
it("getFooCount success", function () {
    httpBackend.whenGET('/api/getFooCount').respond(1);

    fooService.getFooCount();
    httpBackend.flush();
    expect(fooService.FooCount).toBe(1);
});
```

fails: "Expected null to be 1"
(fooService.fooCount is null before the api get method is called).

Yet this test passes:

```
it("getFooCount success", function () {
    httpBackend.whenGET('/api/getFooCount').respond("1");

    fooService.getFooCount();
    httpBackend.flush();
    expect(fooService.fooCount).toBe("1");
});
```

It seems to be able to pass the test with anything (an object, string, array, etc) EXCEPT a number in the `.respond()`.

The api I am calling just returns an integer, any advice as to how I can get this to work, and/or why it is failing?

Comment: It's possible you need to call $digest on the scope to see the change, there might be an odd reason why that's only an issue with numbers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the API for respond, because the first argument is actually the status code.

Try instead respond(200, 1).

Angularjs seems to smart its way around when you provide a non statist object as first parameter